# No SoapException thrown even if server returns SOAP-ENV:Fault

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, exception

Normally client proxies deriving from SoapHttpClientProtocol throw an exception if the webservice returns an error. But I now have the case where definitively the server returns a soap error the client does not throw an exception, so the client has no way to know if the call suceeded or not (webservice has no return type).

What could cause this behaviour?

This is what the server returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 04 Mar 2011 15:57:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.52 OpenSSL/0.9.8m DAV/2
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Mar 2011 15:57:32 GMT
Content-Length: 602
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
         <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>HDHPSPRT2</faultstring>
            <detail>HDHPSPRT2</detail>
         </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service is violating the SOAP protocol. Faults must be returned as a 4xx or 5xx HTTP status code.

Comment: we are using gSOAP at server side. should't the library manage this kind of stuff for us?

Comment: @codymanix: I would say that it _should_ handle it, and that apparently it does _not_ handle it.